# List all suggested fields given the label

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a field that has a label like `First Name`. Now I have a user defined field that he chooses or types. Once he submits the typed label I want to give him the list of suggested fields that he can map to.

So If user submitted a field labels: `Name`, `First`, `Hello` would get suggested field `First Name` for both `Name` and `First`.

I am not asking for code. I just need an algorithm I can follow to do this.

**Note:** I can not use simple **CONTAINS** method since there might be two or three words in user submitted label and I need to match any of those words to existing fields.

Any mapping algorithms would be appreciated. All I need is name of algorithm and I'll figure it out myself.

**Logic of suggested fields:**

If its an exact match display all the way on top
If one word matches only display in the middle
If few characters match consecutively put them all the way on the bottom

Comment: You can use `implode()` to take a list of whatever your users submit, which will turn it into an Array. You can then do whatever you want with the data. Check each possible word, create an array of your proper field names to return. Probably will want to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should split user input into an array of words.

After that you can use approximate search, such as [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), to calculate distance between each label in user input and your fields. Suggest fields that have distance less than some threshold and sorted ascending by resulting distance.

Note, that original Levenshtein distance algorithm calculates distance between whole strings. If you want to match 'Name' to 'First Name' you should use modification that matches any substring. I have a sample code in C#, hope it can help with your PHP implementation:  http:// ideone.com/V0avT4